# Getting error 521 after creating AMI on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am seeking suggestions of what I can do to get my site back online.

Encountered an Error 521 – which in the past I made AMI image on AWS and restarted the instances to get back online. But it didn’t help. DNS register with Cloudflare.

Comment: Any solutions? im facing the same thing now.

Answer (score 0):

Error 521 in CloudFlare is related to 504 error means "Server Not Found".
In your case please check instance public IP or ARN is changed or not, Most probably it is going to changed. In AWS when you restart your Instance via stop and start your public IP is going to change (Not is case of Static IP).

If IP and ARN is Ok then login to your instance and check webserver is running or not on specified port.